# Read DBF file: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException

Tags: c#, dbf, oledbconnection

I am trying to open a DBF in C# file and upload it to a MySQL database. Right now I am just trying to open the DBF file, but I am getting the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.

Unrecognized database format 'C:\Users\Path\..\..\..\SOMEFILE.DBF'.
```

My code is as follows.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"\\", @"\\"));
    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(file.Name);
        string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + file.Name;
        string strAccessSelect = "SELECT * FROM "+file.Name.Substring(0,file.Name.Length-4);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;

        try
        {
            myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a database connection. \n{0}", ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

            myAccessConn.Open();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            myAccessConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I only get the first `MessageBox` with the file name and then it throws the error.

Comment: Post your stack trace please.

Comment: hmm is that Dbase/Foxpro database you are trying to connect? In foxpro dbf I think the data source should be the folder name check https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/

Comment: user908759：What problem have u got? Please remove try……catch block to see at which statement, which error type and msg have you got now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string should identify that the OleDB data source is a DBASE type:

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties=dBase III";
```

Also note that when connecting to DBase via OleDB, you do not specify the DBF file,  but rather the folder which contains it. The individual files are tables.

Answer (score 2):

Use datasource without file name, only path.

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir;
```